# c++ text based duel game, buggy turn mechanic

Tags: c++, turn-based, text, visual-studio, text-based

so ive checked this code 100 times for mistakes and everything checks out and should be working, I've tried everything I can think of but for some reason nothing works, this makes the movement super buggy and none of my attack works

this is a snippet from my initiation class

```
Frame();

Counter = 1;
//Player One's turn
while (Counter == 1) 
{

    Map::Movement();
    Attack::Playerattack();
}
//Player two's turn
while (Counter == 2)
{
    Map::Movement2();
    Attack2::Playerattack();
}
```

part of my movement class

```
int ch;
switch (ch = _getch())
{
    //Player 1 movement
case KEY_W: //up
    if (Player::posy != 1)
    {
        Player::posy--; 
        DisplayMap(); 
        Start::Counter++;
    }
    break;

case KEY_S: //down
    if (Player::posy != 20)
    {
        Player::posy++; 
        DisplayMap(); 
        Start::Counter++;
    }
    break;

case KEY_A: //left
    if (Player::posx != 1)
    {
        Player::posx--; 
        DisplayMap(); 
        Start::Counter++;
    }
    break;

case KEY_D: //right
    if (Player::posx != 20)
    {
        Player::posx++; 
        DisplayMap();
        Start::Counter++;
    }
    break;
```

1st attack class

```
int ch;
switch (ch = _getch())
{
    case KEY_1:
        if (((Player::posx == Player2::posx) && (Player::posy == Player2::posy + Player::roa1)) || ((Player::posx == Player2::posx) && (Player::posy == Player2::posy - Player::roa1)) || ((Player::posy == Player2::posy) && (Player::posx == Player2::posx + Player::roa1)) || ((Player::posy == Player2::posy) && (Player::posx == Player2::posx - Player::roa1)))
        {
            Player2::hp = Player2::hp - Player::doa1;
            std::cout << "You have used: Attack 1" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Player 2 HP is now: " << Player2::hp << std::endl;
            Start::Counter++;
        } 

//if enemy is in range of attack 2 below the monster 
    case KEY_2:
        if (((Player::posx == Player2::posx) && (Player::posy == Player2::posy + Player::roa2)) || ((Player::posx == Player2::posx) && (Player::posy == Player2::posy - Player::roa2)) || ((Player::posy == Player2::posy) && (Player::posx == Player2::posx + Player::roa2)) || ((Player::posy == Player2::posy) && (Player::posx == Player2::posx - Player::roa2)))
        {
            Player2::hp = Player2::hp - Player::doa1;
            std::cout << "You have used: Attack 2" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "player 2 HP is now: " << Player2::hp << std::endl;
            Start::Counter++;
```

2nd Attack class

```
int ch;
switch (ch = _getch())
{
    case KEY_K:
        if (((Player2::posx == Player::posx) && (Player2::posy == Player::posy + Player2::roa1)) || ((Player2::posx == Player::posx) && (Player2::posy == Player::posy - Player2::roa1)) || ((Player2::posy == Player::posy) && (Player2::posx == Player::posx + Player2::roa1)) || ((Player2::posy == Player::posy) && (Player2::posx == Player::posx - Player2::roa1)))
        {
            Player::hp = Player::hp - Player2::doa1;
            std::cout << "Player 1 HP is now: " << Player2::hp << std::endl;
            Start::Counter--;
        } 

    case KEY_L:
        if (((Player2::posx == Player::posx) && (Player2::posy == Player::posy + Player2::roa2)) || ((Player2::posx == Player::posx) && (Player2::posy == Player::posy - Player2::roa2)) || ((Player2::posy == Player::posy) && (Player2::posx == Player::posx + Player2::roa2)) || ((Player2::posy == Player::posy) && (Player2::posx == Player::posx - Player2::roa2)))
        {
            Player::hp = Player::hp - Player2::doa1;
            std::cout << "player 1 HP is now: " << Player2::hp << std::endl;
            Start::Counter--;
```

if anyone has ANY ideas what im doing wrong or have overlooked please tell me and I will try it, I'm working in visual studio 2012.

Comment: just realized i forgot to post the snippet for player 2's movement its basically the same as player 1's but different keys and the counter subtracts rather than adds

Comment: I don't think the issues you're observing come from the code you've posted, at least not that I can see. Could you edit your question and share more of your initiation class?

Comment: You're missing `break`s in your attack class `switch` statements.

Comment: @ChrisMills-Price the rest if the code worked fine before I added the Counter, and thats the only place its referenced inside the initiation class

Comment: @MooseBoys I'll try that and see if it worls thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you lack a break in the attack class, without it the code will fall through and execute every other case.

Secondly and more importantly a player can move and attack in the same turn and and increment/decrement the counter by two. I'm assuming you're going for an either/or situation in which case try this:

Initiation

```
//Player x's turn
ch = _getch()
while (Counter == x)
{
    Counter += Map::Movement(ch);
    if (Counter == x)
    {
        Counter += Attack::Playerattack(ch);
    }
}
```

Then modify the movement and attack classes to use the parameter and return 1/-1 if value has been changed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll add all this during programming class today!

Comment: ok so, I tried what you told me, but now no players can move, I tried checked the value of counter which is working fine but I can't seem to get the player to move now

Answer (score 0):

Ok so if anyone was wondering in the movement and attack classes i set the counter exactly to what i wanted instead of using increments and that seemed to fix the problem